# How can the first of these two code snippets run 3x faster than the second when its doing more work?

Tags: c#, performance, x86, jit, x86-64

How can this code:

```
var check = 0;

for (var numerator = 0; numerator <= maxNumerator; numerator++)
{
    check += numerator >= 0
           ? numerator - (int) ((numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift) * qdi.Number
           : numerator - (int) -((-numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift) * qdi.Number;
}

return check;
```

run 3x faster than this code:

```
var check = 0;

for (var numerator = 0; numerator <= maxNumerator; numerator++)
{
    check += numerator >= 0
           ? (int) ((numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift)
           : (int) -((-numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift);
}

return check;
```

The first code snippet does exactly the same fast divide operation (thats the multiply then shift right) but also a subtraction and multiplication but but the JIT compiler appears to be producing slower code.

I have the disassembly code for each available.
The slower code pushes the rbx register and subtracts 10h from rsp at the start and then adds it back and pops rbx at the end whereas the faster codes doesn't.
The slower code also uses the r11 register for most things where the faster code uses rdx.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clutching at straws but I wonder if this is to do with Data widths; the JIT does take into account the size of data when it chooses how to optimise the code.  What happens if you wrap either loop with an unsafe block ?

Comment: Try running the snippets in reverse order. Could it be that you're experiencing cache misses?

Comment: Think this is a good question for Raymond Chen!  Oh another thought, it's using R11 and RDX because it's targeting x64 I believe, what happens if you target x86 specifically ?

Comment: Russ C: Code was for Any CPU but I've tried x64 and X86 with the same result; also tried unsafe - still the same.  
Not sure what you mean by Data widths - all int except .Multiplier which is a long; identical in both scenarios.  

Steven: Have run them individually as unit tests and as a Console app individually. Always the same.

Comment: Well blow me!
If I change the code to use if/else rather than ? : then it is 3 times quicker!!
Bit worrying to be honest!

Comment: I don't believe this! If I go back to ?: and invert it so the test is '< 0' then I also get the 3x speed increase.

Comment: Very interesting indeed!

Comment: Will post an answer to this question when the 8-hour limit for newbies expires.

Comment: I don't suppose that Raymond Chen bloke has an account here has he?

Comment: @Simon Hewitt: Why would numerator ever be negative given the loop is increasing?

Comment: Don't know to be honest! He was a blog though, the old new thing.  Another Microsoft guy is Eric Lippert who does frequent stack overflow, he might be a good person to ask too.

Comment: @leppie: Thats a reasonable question. These are just unit tests which are showing whether a struct I have is inlining methods or not. So I have tests in threes: One which just does the division as normal; one (as above) where the optimization is written literally inline; and one which calls my Divide method. If the time of the Divide method is roughly that of the literal inline method then I know the method is inlining and will get a 3x speed improvement.

Comment: why don't you divide using the standard operator

Comment: Because multiplying and then shifting is much faster than a standard divide operation. The 'qdi' in the code represents a QuickDivideInfo struct and precomputing the values for my known divisors (hashtable buckets size) into these structs means my UniqueStringList class, which I previously thought was fully optimized, is now twice as fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the condition used in a ternary operation *can* affect the code generated.

It would also appear that a ternary optionation *can* generate less efficient code than a simple if/else.

So changing the loop code in the second snippest to:

```
if (numerator >= 0) check += (int) ((numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift);
else check += (int) -((-numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift);
```

or:

```
if (numerator < 0) check += (int) -((-numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift);
else check += (int) ((numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift);
```

or:

```
check += numerator < 0
    ? (int) -((-numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift)
    : (int) ((numerator * qdi.Multiplier) >> qdi.Shift);
```

will produce the faster running code.

Actually I find it a bit disturbing that three out of four combinations produce fast code but the other can produce slow code... sometimes.

Comment: What is the layout of `QuickDivideInfo struct`?  Also, do you see this same behavior on different machines?

Comment: Code can be seen here [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UniqueStringList2.aspx).
Only got the one machine here but will be updating the article soon with the test code so we shall see!

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring? Your description of the assembly language doesn't sound like something that would make a huge performance difference.

Anyway, if it's really a lot slower, I doubt anyone outside the JIT team can say exactly why this is happening. I have noticed when doing .NET microbenchmarks that seemingly trivial code changes can make the code run significantly faster or slower. If you can make that code (that triggers slowness) as simple as possible, you could complain to MS about it on Microsoft Connect.

You could try copying qdi.Multiplier, qdi.Shift and qdi.Number (whatever they are) to local variables, that sometimes helps.

Comment: It really is a lot slower. The loop shown is being executed 50 times which is timed. And the whole lot is looped 10 times to get 10 different timings. A full GC is run between passes (including waiting for pending finalizers) and the thread priority is set to AboveNormal to reduce interruptions as far as possible.

When running slow it takes ~10 secs, when running fast it takes ~3.2 secs. That is not a trival difference. :-)

Comment: I agree that local variables can be slightly quicker but thats not the point in this case. The compiler *should* produce identical code in all four scenarios (?: with >= 0; ?: with < 0; if/then with >=0 and if/then with < 0)